# some rendering template in flask are without css

Tags: flask

i have 3 routes and one of them hasnt css style.
actually `/en_blog/sd and /en/` work fine.
but  if i try this route `/en/blog/` template will show without any style.
how i can fix it?
this is my flask view code

```
@core.route('/en/')
def en_home():
    return render_template('en_home.html')

@core.route('/en/blog/')
def en_blog():
    return render_template('en_blog.html')

@core.route('/en_blog/')
def en_siteintroducing():
    return render_template('en_blog.html')
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. Look at blueprint package. Read that if needed :  https://realpython.com/flask-blueprint/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462914/extend-a-blueprint-in-flask-splitting-it-into-several-files and https://blog.macuyiko.com/post/2016/fixing-flask-url_for-when-behind-mod_proxy.html

Comment: As mentioned, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed here. Consider also merging these routes together -- they all point to the same thing, so just stack the decorators on top of each other (e.g. as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023664/flask-url-route-route-several-urls-to-the-same-function)).